# Reset the input if there's a value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm not good at scripting and did the following by some trial and error. It seems to be working, but I wonder if it's the right way to reset the text field if there's a value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reset</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="box">
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="zero();">
    <script>
        var box = document.getElementById('box');

        function zero() {
            if (box.value && confirm('Sure?')) {
                box.value = '';
                alert('Done!');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you aware there is an `<input type="reset">` button?

Comment: Yes, I am. The above is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me outline some problems in your code - you stated you are looking for the right way.

- You are using the [outdated inline event model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html) (putting Javascript into HTML attributes), which has several drawbacks. You said you are not good in scripting. If you want to learn it, you could learn it the right way, you have nothing to lose. I suggest using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- You could make your function reusable. In its current state, it is only useful to reset a very specific input element, and this is not really what functions are for.

I created a quick little example, for illustration.

In the HTML I removed the inline `onclick`. I added an `id` for the button to be able to reference it, and added a `data-reset` attribute ([HTML5 `data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)), in which we can store the `id` for the element the button will reset:

```
<input type="text" id="box">
<input id="reset-button" type="button" value="Reset" data-reset="box" />
```

And here comes the new JS, commented:

```
//get the reset button from the DOM
var resetButton = document.getElementById('reset-button');

//add a click event listener to it, our reset function will handle the event
resetButton.addEventListener('click', reset);

//and the reset function
function reset() {
    //`this` refers to the clicked button - we query the data- attribute
    var inputId = this.getAttribute('data-reset');
    //get the right input element
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    //and then what you already had
    if (input.value && confirm('Sure?')) {
        input.value = '';
        alert('Done!');
    }
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/vxy4x/)

Now the code uses the modern event model, and the function is reusable on any other button or for a different text field - you just have to change the `data-` attribute.

I don't say this is the very very best way, but I wanted to keep it easy and understandable.

Comment: I am giving you an upvote for a more complete and thoughtful solution.  I guess the only thing left to be said is that users should be cautious that older browsers and specifically IE8 don't support the addEventListener method to register events (10% of the world still uses the terrible browser).

Comment: @Nate But old IEs support `attachEvent`, which can be used if `addEventListener` is not supported. It is discussed on the [MDN page I've linked in my answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility).

Comment: I am aware of the attachEvent, thank you for mentioning it for others and updating your answer.

Comment: I was also thinking, since you put in the extra effort of making the reset button reusable, you may want to demonstrate how you would attach another listener to at least one more element (to illustrate how the callback method is reusable) in case that might not be clear to OP.

Comment: @Nate I hope the linked resources (and maybe some searches) will help him, my answer is quite long already.

Answer (score 1):

```
function zero() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    if (box.value && confirm('Sure?')) {
        box.value = '';
        alert('Done!');
    }
 }
```

Your code is fine, with the only exception of moving the box variable into the function scope (instead of global scope) if you only need to reference it there (better memory management as it will be collected as garbage when the function is done executing).

Comment: Well, if we are micro-optimizing, we must state that the OP's code queries the DOM only once for the element. I don't think your code is any better or anywhere closer to the right way than the OP's...

Comment: Kapa, I stated "if you only need to reference it there."  In the code OP provided, the only reference to the value is when the reset button is pushed.  If OP made other references to the value in his code it would make sense in global scope, however, keeping a handle to it in memory would otherwise be wasteful.  The first thing I also stated was "Your code is fine" and so with the exception of the variable scope, I am in agreeance with you that the code is otherwise fine for what has been asked.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the input value outside of the function which is wrong.

```
function zero() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    if (box.value != ""){
        if(confirm('Sure?')){
            box.value = '';
            alert('Done!');
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqAY2/1/)

Comment: I imagine OP probably wants to keep that `confirm()` in there.

Comment: Where's the confirmation?

Comment: This one does not really make a real difference and does not get any closer to the "right way" the OP asked for.

Comment: why 2 downvate because of this `if (box.value != "")`

Comment: @SumanBogati I've seen it. The only things you did is that you moved getting the DOM element into the function (does not really matter in this case) and got rid of `&&`, which was perfectly fine.